# Msys cd .. command takes me to home directory instead of parent

Tags: windows, bash, msys

I'm using Msys on Windows 7 with what I believe to be a Bash shell.

I want to navigate the following directory structure:

```
Drive (M:)
+--- Coding
   +--- CPP
      +--- projects
      +--- other_folder_1
      +--- other_folder_2
```

My fstab file contains the following line:

```
M:/Coding/CPP/projects/ /home/Adrian/
```

... which makes the projects folder my starting directory when opening the shell.

Unfortunately when I try to **cd ..** out of **projects**, I end up in **/home** instead of **CPP**.

I imagine this might be related to what I did in the fstab file. Is there any way for me to retain the projects folder as my starting directory while being able to **cd** into its parent directories?